# Different Text font at each line of UIlabel

Tags: ios, uilabel, uifont

Is there any way to give different font size to each line of a label with "n" no of lines.
I dont want to take multiple labels for this purpose.
plz help!!!

Answer (score 4):

Starting with iOS 6, you can use [`NSAttributedString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in `UILabel`.

> An `NSAttributedString` object manages character strings and associated sets of attributes (for example, font and kerning) that apply to individual characters or ranges of characters in the string.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attrStr = ...
myLabel.attributedText = attrStr;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but You have to use UIWebView, pass your text in html format.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting iOS < 6.0 then by using UILabel its not at all possible. Else you can refer dasblinkenlight answer (for iOS > 6)

There are couple of methods by which you can implement same :

1. Use `UIWebView`
2. Create `UILabel` for different fonts you want and set their frame as you want to display.

Comment: It is possible with UILabel starting with iOS6.

Answer (score 0):

`UILabel` with [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html)(iOS 6 and later).

Or `UIWebView` with html-strings, but my favorit is a `UITextView` with html-strings. You can use it like this:

```
UITextView *tView=[UITextView new];
[tView setValue:@"<b>foo</b>bar" forKey:@"contentToHTMLString"];
```

`UITextView`s are easier to handle then `UIWebView`, especially if you don't need all the functionality of the WebView.